# What is the right way to say that, "his credit balance is likely to be in deficit"

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, connotation

I want to say that that 'x' person spends a lot and his credit balance is likely to become negative.

```
"With multiple ...., his balance is likely to be in deficit."

 OR 

 "With multiple ...., his balance is likely to become negative."
```

I'm not sure which of them is correct, please let me know if there is a third and better way to phrase this idea.

Comment: His balance is likely to go into  the red!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally expect the former. Balances tend to be described as being in credit or deficit / debit.

> "With multiple ...., his balance is likely to be in debit"

You might also use:

> "With multiple ...., his balance is likely to be overdrawn"

A straw poll in my office seems to imply that debit / deficit is more commonly used by American English, and Overdraft by UK English, although both are understood.